# How to "grep -v" private/broadcast IPv4 addresses?

Tags: regular-expression, ip

```
time nmap -n -iR 0 -sL | cut -d " " -f 5 | egrep -v "^10.*|^172.[16\-32].*|^192.168.*|^[224\-255].*" > RANDOM-IPS.txt
```

so the important part is:

```
egrep -v "^10.*|^172.[16\-32].*|^192.168.*|^[224\-255].*"
```

**Q**: Is this a good regexp? /So I will generate all the 2^32 IPv4 addresses, and "grep -v" the private/broadcast ranges./ Or are there any  better ways to generate the usable IPv4 addresses on the internet?

Comment: This regexp doesn't do what you want because `[16\-32]` doesn't mean what you think it means (did you even try it?). See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19610/how-to-filter-ipv4-and-ipv6-addresses/19619#19619) for an example of matching numeric ranges with regexps. This is a pretty strange way of generating non-private IPv4 addresses (you missed some non-usable addresses by the way, such as loopback and the example ranges). Generating “all” IPv4 is a pretty silly goal anyway, what are you going to do with the result?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally a bit toilsome regex to write if you type it in a single command. Better than this, you can make use of `grep`'s **`-f`** option :

> ```
>  -f FILE, --file=FILE
>       Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
>       contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
>       specified by POSIX.)
> ```

So create a file, where on each line you'll have a regex to match a particular IP family/range. And then, use the `-f` option in conjunction with `-v`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not about how to generate random IPv4 addresses, but rather about how one may go about filtering out the IPs that fall within the private network ranges `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12`, and `192.168.0.0/16`.

Using [`grepcidr`](http://www.pc-tools.net/unix/grepcidr/):

```
$ nmap -n -iR 0 -sL | cut -d " " -f 5 | grepcidr -v 10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
```

Notice, though, that

> Undesirable IPs such as those in certain
>              private, multicast, or unallocated address ranges are automatically
>              skipped.

(from the `nmap` 7.40 manual, about `-iR`)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is the POSIX style answer to this question that I just spent half an hour working up:

```
grep -Ev '10\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | grep -Ev '172\.1[6-9]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|172\.2[0-9]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|172\.3[0-1]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | grep -Ev '192\.168\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
```

This should output only valid IP addresses in the private RFC1918 address space.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can condense that middle part into `172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` (minus any typos), and I don't think you need three separate greps either, just join all variants with `|`. Or use multiple `-e` options. With `-v`, you're excluding the matches, not outputting them.