# Regular expression in Bash to validate IP-address

Tags: bash, regular-expression

In my Python script i have a regular expression for searching IP-addresses like 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 in a file, it looks like this:

```
[1-2]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{1}\.[1-2]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{1}\.[1-2]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{1}\.[1-2]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{1}
```

Now i need to have the same in a Bash script. So i changed it like this:

```
[1-2]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1\}\.[1-2]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1\}\.[1-2]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1\}\.[1-2]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1\}
```

Works almost fine but for some reason it filters addresses like "1000.0.0", "2323.23.23.2323" and so on. Why is that so.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19610/how-to-filter-ipv4-and-ipv6-addresses/19619#19619

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `python` regexp is using the extended regular expression syntax which comes from the `egrep` command in the 70s (though the `{...}` part was added later, and actually in `grep` before `egrep`).

POSIX have consolidated the `grep` and `egrep` commands (`egrep` is now `grep -E`) in the 90s and standardized the `{x,y}` operator (which wasn't available in the earlier `egrep`s).

So now, you should be able to use `grep -E 'that-regexp'` with all modern `grep` implementations.

Note that your regexp would allow 299.299.299.299 and the `{1}`s are redundant. `{0,1}` can be shortened to `?`.

Note that `grep` find *lines* that match the regexp, that is lines that contain a string that match the regexp anywhere. Use `^` and `$` to anchor, or use the `-x` option to `grep`.

Answer (score 9):

Tried to shorten the regexp, here is the result:

```
#!/bin/bash

rx='([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'

for ip in 08.08.08.08 3.3.3.3 11.11.11.11 \
      111.123.11.99 \
      222.2.3.4 999.88.9.9 \
      255.255.255.255 255.0.3.3 0.256.0.222; do

   if [[ $ip =~ ^$rx\.$rx\.$rx\.$rx$ ]]; then
      echo "valid:     "$ip
   else
      echo "not valid: "$ip
   fi
done
```

Comment: Note that it says `08.08.08.08` is valid.

Comment: Do you mean that leading zeros are not allowed?

Comment: I mean that leading zero usually means octal in IP address, and `08` is not a valid octal. In firefox for instance, if you enter `http://010.010.010.010`, you query 8.8.8.8, and if you query `http://08.08.08.08`, firefox tries to resolve it as a hostname as it's not a valid IP address.

Comment: That's new to me, could you check again?

Comment: Looks alright now. Further reading in the man pages of inet_addr (BSD/POSIX syntax very widespread), inet_pton (only decimal only quad, up to 3 digits allowed per component). `gethostbyname` and `getaddrinfo` usually support the same as `inet_addr`. Then, you can have everything in between. If checking the sanity of input, I think your latest solution is the safest. `010.010.010.010` is valid for most tools but do not necessarily mean the same for all, so it's better to reject it.

Answer (score 5):

I think this should cover it

```
$ octet="(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])"
```

Or to avoid zeros on the left:

```
$ octet="(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])"
```

You can then make use of `$octet`:

```
$ ip4="^$octet\\.$octet\\.$octet\\.$octet$"
$ echo $ip4
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]?[0-9])$
$ [[ 123.234.12.34 =~ $ip4 ]] && echo y || echo n
y
$ [[ 123.234.12.345 =~ $ip4 ]] && echo y || echo n
n
```

Comment: @p.glez: your edit is not necessary. The original "octet" regex will match all of "007", "07" and "7" due to the use of the `?` quantifier. Your regex cannot match the valid IP address 127.001.001.001

Answer (score 1):

you can integrate this function with your code to validate IP Address. If you can share your current code, I can be more specific to the problem.

```
function validateIP()
 {
         local ip=$1
         local stat=1
         if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
                OIFS=$IFS
                IFS='.'
                ip=($ip)
                IFS=$OIFS
                [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 \
                && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
                stat=$?
        fi
        return $stat
}

echo "Enter IP Address"
read ip
validateIP $ip

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];then
  echo "Invalid IP Address ($ip)"
else
  echo "$ip is a Perfect IP Address"
fi
```

Comment: This returns false for valid IP addresses, for example, `127.1` is a valid IP address.

Comment: It also returns false for `0111.0111.0111.0111` or `08.08.08.08` (that one with a _value too great for base_ error)

Comment: BTW, depending on who you're asking, `08.08.08.08` is valid or not, and `010.010.010.010` means `8.8.8.8` (most common) or `10.10.10.10`

Comment: @Stephane - Thanks for your attention, I think this `08.08.08.08` is considered as an `Octal value` by the server because 0 is defines Octal number, so server is ignoring that value.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas I understand why most implementations interpret leading zeros as octal but RFC 1123 specifically says an all-numeric a.b.c.d is dotted decimal.  010 should be decimal 10 not decimal 8.

Comment: @DougO'Neal, that's not a requirement, but a recommendation. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-00 for more info.