# Sed: Replace ANY IP address with 127.0.0.1

Tags: text-processing, sed, ip-address

I'm trying to do an in-place replacement of an IP address in a file using sed. I know that . is a wildcard, so I've tried doing the following:

`sed -i -e 's/.\..\..\..\./127.0.0.1/g' /.../myfile.txt`

however I'm not sure how many digits each section of the IP address could be (1-3), and I'm also not sure if my escape works as well. Any advice? Much appreciated

Comment: Related: [How to filter IPv4 and IPv6 addresses?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19610/how-to-filter-ipv4-and-ipv6-addresses?)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because the others are more complex examples and not everyone can understand those regex. A simplier, non-validated, non-ipv6 answer could be useful too. `sed -i -r 's#[1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.[1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.[1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.[1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]#127.0.0.1#g' myfile.txt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[0-9]` matches any digit.

`[0-9]\{1,3\}` matches between 1 and 3 digits (note that this will accept leading zeroes.

Therefore,

```
sed -i -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/127.0.0.1/g' /.../myfile.txt
```

should do roughly what you want. It will match some invalid addresses, but will probably do the job.  For a more advanced option see link from @steeldriver in comments