# Find IP addresses in file excluding local IPs

Tags: awk, sed, grep, ip

**The task**: find and print lines from a file that contain any (IPv4) IP address except those on the local LAN (local LAN uses class C addresses of the 192.168.1.x variety). I (having cribbed bits from various online searches) use `sed` and a couple of pipes to do this fairly effectively, as follows:

```
sed -rn '/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/p' logfile.txt | sed '/192\.168\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\{,3\}/d'
```

**Question**: are there other or better ways of doing this using alternate utilities, or perhaps improvements I could make to the incantation I've come up with?

**Background**: the purpose is, on a non-systemd (Void Linux) system, to trawl daily a system log file that contains ssh connection information to see who, other than hosts on my local LAN, has been trying to make ssh connections/queries. The file containing the target information is generated daily using `svlogtail`, after which the above command runs. The system then e-mails me the output.

***Sample input data***:

```
2020-06-21T08:28:04.56472 auth.err: sshd[21813]: error: Bind to port 22 on 192.168.2.16 failed: Cannot assign requested address.  
2020-06-23T11:12:59.04698 auth.info: Jun 23 06:12:59 sshd[25036]: banner exchange: Connection from 194.61.24.4 port 1565: invalid format  
2020-07-14T14:53:30.54107 auth.info: Jul 14 09:53:30 sshd[30149]: banner exchange: Connection from 31.207.47.114 port 1848: invalid format  
2020-09-06T15:25:19.32385 auth.info: Sep  6 10:25:19 sshd[18826]: banner exchange: Connection from 193.142.146.216 port 30884: invalid format  
2021-01-30T16:03:43.39251 auth.info: Jan 30 10:03:43 sshd[32208]: rexec line 80: Unsupported option GSSAPIAuthentication  
2021-02-05T12:24:30.42762 auth.info: Feb  5 06:24:30 sshd[27489]: banner exchange: Connection from 94.232.47.170 port 107: invalid format  
2021-02-19T15:48:10.29592 auth.info: Feb 19 09:48:10 sshd[2924]: Disconnected from user 192.168.1.10 port 33732
```

***Desired output*** (this acceptable output is what I get after running above `sed` commands)

```
2020-06-23T11:12:59.04698 auth.info: Jun 23 06:12:59 sshd[25036]: banner exchange: Connection from 194.61.24.4 port 1565: invalid format  
2020-07-14T14:53:30.54107 auth.info: Jul 14 09:53:30 sshd[30149]: banner exchange: Connection from 31.207.47.114 port 1848: invalid format  
2020-09-06T15:25:19.32385 auth.info: Sep  6 10:25:19 sshd[18826]: banner exchange: Connection from 193.142.146.216 port 30884: invalid format  
2021-02-05T12:24:30.42762 auth.info: Feb  5 06:24:30 sshd[27489]: banner exchange: Connection from 94.232.47.170 port 107: invalid format
```

**Later summary** The most elegant way to do this sort of thing definitely seems to be `grepcidr`. Had I known about it prior to trying to accomplish this task I definitely would have used it. I am going to mark the response that suggests using it as the answer, even though there are mutliple ways, including the `sed` commands and pipes I posted, to accomplish the same goal. The `grepcidr` command does have much greater adaptability for these sorts of tasks, as multiple address ranges can be specified far more easily than would be the case if attempting to use `sed` or `grep`.

Btw, I've also discovered a couple of `grep` commands that, when piped together, also give the same result, as follows:

```
grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' logfile.txt | grep -v 192.168.[[:digit:]].[[:digit:]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter IPv4 and IPv6 addresses?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19610/how-to-filter-ipv4-and-ipv6-addresses)

Comment: My post seeks alternate, perhaps better, ways of doing what the commands listed do. Namely finding all lines in a file that contain ipv4 address but excluding lines containing IP's in the class C range specified. Proposals at the link are simply for finding IP's without excluding some.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: This is a horrible hack, but a little easier. `sed -i '/192.168.*/d' ./file_name.txt` - which gives you the output you're already getting in a shorter format. It removes all lines that have 192.168.* in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to filter out the lines that contain an address in the `192.168.0.0/16` block. You may do this with `grepcidr`:

```
$ grepcidr -v '192.168.0.0/16' file
2020-06-23T11:12:59.04698 auth.info: Jun 23 06:12:59 sshd[25036]: banner exchange: Connection from 194.61.24.4 port 1565: invalid format
2020-07-14T14:53:30.54107 auth.info: Jul 14 09:53:30 sshd[30149]: banner exchange: Connection from 31.207.47.114 port 1848: invalid format
2020-09-06T15:25:19.32385 auth.info: Sep 6 10:25:19 sshd[18826]: banner exchange: Connection from 193.142.146.216 port 30884: invalid format
2021-02-05T12:24:30.42762 auth.info: Feb 5 06:24:30 sshd[27489]: banner exchange: Connection from 94.232.47.170 port 107: invalid format
```

Or, if you want to use a specific range, such as "between 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.2.255":

```
$ grepcidr -v '192.168.1.0-192.168.2.255' file
2020-06-23T11:12:59.04698 auth.info: Jun 23 06:12:59 sshd[25036]: banner exchange: Connection from 194.61.24.4 port 1565: invalid format
2020-07-14T14:53:30.54107 auth.info: Jul 14 09:53:30 sshd[30149]: banner exchange: Connection from 31.207.47.114 port 1848: invalid format
2020-09-06T15:25:19.32385 auth.info: Sep 6 10:25:19 sshd[18826]: banner exchange: Connection from 193.142.146.216 port 30884: invalid format
2021-02-05T12:24:30.42762 auth.info: Feb 5 06:24:30 sshd[27489]: banner exchange: Connection from 94.232.47.170 port 107: invalid format
```

To filter out all private IPv4 blocks, use

```
grepcidr -v '10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16' file
```

`grepcidr` should also understand IPv6, but since I don't, I won't show an example.

Comment: Very interesting. I was not aware of this utility but do see it in Void repositories. It does look like the ideal tool to use for a task like this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `grep` and `PCRE` are the best tool for such jobs:

```
grep -Po "(?<=from )(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?= port)" file | grep -Ev "^192\.168\.1\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}$"
```

Assuming your network have default C class mask `/24`.

A better approach should be to skip logging for the desired hosts, such as lan hosts in your case.

Furthermore the output of your logger are not ideally for parsing. A better logger, like logging module
of `iptables` firewall
show entry for parsing in a more sophisticated way:

```
Feb 27 00:32:33 hostname kernel: [181663.827178] [HTTPS-ATTEMPT]IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa:08:00 SRC=X.X.X.X DST=X.X.X.X LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=242 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=42717 DPT=443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

If you can skip logging for local lan host then the `grep` could stop at the first without pipe for the second round.

@Praveen Kumar BS make me think to a good `python` module for doing this job: `ipaddrress`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import ipaddress
import re

lan = ipaddress.IPv4Network("192.168.1.0/24")

with open("stack.log", 'r') as log:
    for line in log:
        curr_ip = re.search(r'(?<=from )(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b', line)
        if curr_ip and not ipaddress.IPv4Address(curr_ip.group()) in lan:
            print(curr_ip.group())
```

with `ipaddress` you can build an address from a regexp capture and check if it is in a given network, `lan`, in my example.

Comment: The grep command given in this answer captures only IP's, not surrounding context from the line containing the IP as I'd stipulated.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep` or any `grep` with `perl`-like regexp support, you can use the negative look-ahead operator:

```
grep -P '\b(?!192\.168\.)(\d{1,3})(\.(?1)){3}\b'
```

Or directly with `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if /\b(?!192\.168\.)(\d{1,3})(\.(?1)){3}\b/'
```

Those report the lines that contain a quad-decimal representation of an IP address other than those starting with `192.168.`, even if those lines also contain a `192.168.x.y` IP address.

For a stricter matching of IP addresses, you could use the `Regexp::Common::net` module:

```
perl -MRegexp::Common=net -ne '
  print if m{
    \b$RE{net}{IPv4}{-keep}\b
    (?(?{$2 == 192 && $3 == 168}) (*FAIL))
  }x'
```

Answer (score 0):

command:

```
awk '!/192.168.*.*/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$/){print $i}}}' filename
```

output

```
194.61.24.4
31.207.47.114
193.142.146.216
94.232.47.170
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(r'192.168.*.*')
c=re.compile(r'^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*')
m=open('p.txt','r')
for i in m:
    if not re.search(k,i):
        z=i.split(' ')
        for v in range(0,len(z),1):
            if re.search(c,z[v]):
                print z[v]
```

output

```
194.61.24.4
31.207.47.114
193.142.146.216
94.232.47.170
```

Comment: This is an interesting proposal but seems to exclude important context attending the target IP's. As mentioned, I want the whole line where the IP appears, not just the IP itself. The context around the IP is important because it tells me when the attempt happened and a little about what sort of attempt was made.